# Не создаётся тег <div> на странице

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

На странице должен появиться тег , но он не появляется. Как исправить, чтобы он появлялся?

```js
let out = document.getElementById('out');

class Table {
  constructor(el) {
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
    this.el.innerHTML = 'Hello there!';
  }
  out.appendChild(el);
}

let table = new Table(el);
```

```css
div {
  height: 25px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<p id="out"></p>
```

Comment: Что насчет "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." в строке `out.appendChild(el);`? Почему эта строка болтается вне конструктора?

Comment: Не хватает опыта работы с классами. Никак не могу понять, что за проблема. Получается, надо строку out.appendChild(el); добавить в тело конструктора?

Comment: @Alex Что не дает Вам попробовать это сделать?

Comment: Да попробовал, а толку? Выдаёт Uncaught ReferenceError: el is not defined

Comment: @Alex что такое у вас `el`??? данная переменная нигде не определена

Comment: @Alex либо в конструктор, либо в какой-то метод класса - смотря чего вы добиваетесь. В данной ситуации, на самом деле, в первую очередь вам нужно четко представлять что вы хотите сделать, а не иметь опыт работы с классами. Тот же `el`, который принимается в конструктор, никак не используется, а в `new Table` передаётся несуществующий `el`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let out = document.getElementById('out');

class Table {
  constructor(el) {
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
    this.el.innerHTML = 'Hello there!';
    el.appendChild(this.el);
  }
}

let table = new Table(out);
```

```css
#out {
  height: 25px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```